# One case of the menu conditioned by other

Tags: c++, if-statement, menu, case

I have a c++ program with a menu of 9 cases. I need that the case 7 is only executed if the case 3 has been used before case 7. How can I do it?
Thanks.

I don't know how to use a case in an "if".

Comment: its not clear what you are talking about. Please show your code

Comment: Have you considered using the `if` in the `case` rather than the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using an `if` inside a `case` statement:

```
case 7:
{
    if (previous_selection == 3)
    {
        Do_Operation();
    }
}
break;
```

This one of many possible solutions, there are others.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I comprobe that the previous selection was 3?

Comment: You maintain the previous selection.  The `if` statement handles the comprobe.  Or for the  `case` of 3 in the main menu, at the end of `case 3`, you print a menu selection for item 7.

Answer (score 0):

You have to flag somehow that `case 3` has been executed. For example, with a `bool` variable, setting it as part of the `case 3` block of instructions, and checking it as part of the `case 7` block of instructions.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/qrMT3T7EG)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout

int main() {
    bool case_3_already_used{ false };
    for (auto index : { 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 9 }) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0: { std::cout << "0\n"; break; }
            case 1: { std::cout << "1\n"; break; }
            case 2: { std::cout << "2\n"; break; }
            case 3: {
                std::cout << "3\n";
                case_3_already_used = true;
                break;
            }
            case 4: { std::cout << "4\n"; break; }
            case 5: { std::cout << "5\n"; break; }
            case 6: { std::cout << "6\n"; break; }
            case 7: { 
                if (case_3_already_used) {
                    std::cout << "7\n";
                } else {
                    std::cout << "Cannot execute case 7 since case 3 has not been executed yet.\n";
                }
                break;
            }
            case 8: { std::cout << "8\n"; break; }
            case 9: { std::cout << "9\n"; break; }
            default: break;
        }
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   Cannot execute case 7 since case 3 has not been executed yet.
//   6
//   5
//   3
//   2
//   1
//   8
//   7
//   9
```

---

Now, were the `switch` logic in a separate function, you would need to keep the state of that boolean variable between different calls. A way to do that would be to mark the flag as `static`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/1YTxP6zWa)